# Jenkins multi-configuration, ignore failed build

Tags: jenkins, build, erlang, multi-configuration

I've setup a Jenkins multi-configuration project in order to run builds on two different slave environments (Erlang R15B03 and Erlang 17.3). This in order to start preparing our projects for actual release on an 17.3 production environment.

Currently the 17.3 build for all projects is failing because of dependency failures which need to be fixed as we go along, and the R15B03 builds are all passing.

How can I make it so that Jenkins (for now) ignores the 17.3 result and will pass the build as succesful if the R15B03 build passes?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to have a build passing if *anything* goes wrong. It is like commenting out failing tests to fix them later - you forget about them.

You should probably setup two separate jenkins builds for R15 and 17. This way, every time, you will see, that R15B03 passed and 17.3 did not until you fix all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parameterized trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to have a conditional trigger. Setup your multiconfiguration project to always trigger and then check the parameters to decide what downstream build to trigger.